# How to implement OAuth with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oauth, authorization

I have developed an iGoogle gadget. I have to access the spreadsheet of the logged in user.

First of all, how do I check whether user is logged in or not using JavaScript? Later, from the gadget, how will I implement OAuth to grant access to user's spreadsheet using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple implementation of the same can be found [here](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/) Please take a look. It should not take much time.

Comment: I'm developing a windows 7 gadget. This library says it supports windows 7 gadgets as well. But according to my understanding I have to give a call back URL to get the reply. How should I do that?